# Why am I getting permission issues while writing a file even after using --user with chmod777?

Tags: docker, user-permissions

I have built an image and run that container as `--user gauravs`. I used `--user gauravs` to build my image, provided all sudo functionalities to the user and modify the permissions to 777, but still, I am getting a permission error whenever I try to write any file (give commands in my script). I need to manually do `touch \<file\>` then `chmod 777 \<file\>`. May I request you to tell me what I am doing wrong?

What I have found when I run any experiment, `ps aux|grep <pid>` shows some random name associated with it, and that random name is later associated with mine.

```
awoodard 2805117 8778  0.6 27876664 5175500 ?    Rsl  10:31 8783:54 python3 main.py --gpu_num 1
gauravs  2808325  0.0  0.0   9032  2708 pts/1    S+   12:11   0:00 grep --color=auto 2805117
```

The Dockerfile I used:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.1-devel-ubuntu20.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install apt-utils
RUN apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install curl ca-certificates
RUN apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install sudo \
    git \
    bzip2 \
    libx11-6 \
    wget \
    build-essential \
    pkg-config \
    vim

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
VOLUME /app

CMD bash
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
#RUN apt-get  -y --no-install-recommends install python3-dev python3-pip


#ENV user gauravs
#RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --shell /bin/bash ${user} \
#       && chown -R ${user}:${user} /app \
#       && adduser ${user} sudo
#RUN echo "%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" > /etc/sudoers
#USER ${user}

RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' --shell /bin/bash user \
    && chown -R user:user /app \
    && adduser user sudo
RUN echo "%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL">/etc/sudoers
USER user

#ENV PATH=/home/${user}/.local/bin:$PATH
ENV PATH=/home/user/.local/bin:$PATH
RUN sudo chmod 777 -R /app
#RUN sudo chmod 777 /home/${user}
RUN sudo chmod 777 /home/user

RUN sudo apt-get  -y --no-install-recommends install python3-dev
RUN sudo apt-get  -y --no-install-recommends install  python3-pip

# Install Dependencies
RUN pip3 install --user --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip3 install --user wheel
RUN sudo apt-get -y --no-install-recommends  install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 uninstall -y torch
#RUN pip3 install torch==1.8.0+cu111 torchvision==0.9.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.8.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
RUN pip3 install torch==1.11.0+cu113 torchvision==0.12.0+cu113 torchaudio==0.11.0+cu113 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html
RUN pip3 install --user torchtext==0.9.0
```

Comment: Belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network which isn't an option on the close list.... SMH 2022.

Comment: What file are you trying to write?  Is it something that's created in the Dockerfile, a named volume, a bind-mounted directory, or something else?  If you want your user to have unrestricted permissions within the container (so long as it remembers to ask politely) can you run as `USER root` without installing `sudo`?

Comment: Thanks, David for responding. I am trying to write some results in a file during my experiment. I am doing it in a usual way by providing `open(<filename>, 'w')` in the python script. 
I am using this command to run docker container: 
`docker run -itd --rm  --user gauravs  --gpus device=all -v <path/to/dir>:/app --name <container_name> <image_name>`
I don't want to run as root as it will affect other people work.